# Canonical way of testing for str dtype?

Tags: python, numpy, typechecking

What is the recommended way of checking for str (`U...`) dtype? I suppose I could do `dtype.char == "U"` but that feels a bit hackish.

Some `dtypes` can be directly compared to their Python equivalent, for example

```
np.dtype("f8") == float
# True
```

and `str` can be used to create a `U...` array, for example

```
 np.arange(4).astype(str)
 # array(['0', '1', '2', '3'], dtype='<U21')
```

But

```
 np.arange(4).astype(str).dtype == str
 # False
```

:-(

Comment: I feel you on the hackish, but if it works and you like it, that's half the battle. What's the objective? You're just trying to get the `U` dtype of some value?

Comment: @zerecees I need to detect whether the array contains strings or something else.

Comment: Edit with a sample data structure, or comment back saying any ds and I'll answer with some possibilities and timeit's

Comment: Is bytecode an option? `from dis import dis`? Just checking before i potentially go down a rabbit role, which probably isn't worth it anyway but don't want to throw anything out yet.

Comment: What about using instanceof ?

Comment: @zerecees I think you are overthinking this. It's more of a style thing not a hard problem.

Comment: Gotcha, was under the impression we were going for something under the hood. In my opinion, I would do what you're doing. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `np.issubdtype()` should be what you are looking for:

```
>>> s = np.arange(4).astype(str)
>>> s
array(['0', '1', '2', '3'], 
      dtype='<U24')
>>> np.issubdtype(s.dtype, str)
True
```